# Counting unique values among a filtered subset

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet with inspection reports from ships, with divergences reported individually; as a result, a day with several divergences will result in multiple reports. I want to be able to check how many days the vessels have submitted reports for, but because there are hundreds of voyages in the list the usual functions to count unique values have proven unsuitable. Each daily report has a report ID based on its voyage code and how many days into the voyage it is.

For instance, if I have the **Reports** dataset, I want to output the **ReportCount** information. I've had a bit of a think about using `COUNTIFS`, but without much success so far. I'm not committed to using individual report IDs, so I'm quite happy to use a different approach if it would help.

The question, then, is what formula I can use in `ReportCount[Reports]` to count the number of days reports have been submitted for each voyage.

[image: Image showing relationship between reports and report counter]

Can anyone advise?

Comment: Exactly, which one is your question? You have a Report table and a Reports count table.

Comment: What do you need? One formula to count the reports by day? by ship?...

Comment: Clarifying in the question. The aim is to count the number of days each ship has submitted at least one report. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use Power Query (Excel 2010+) to create a count of "distinct" rows.

No need for the Report ID column.

In the Power query editor, just

- `Group By` Voyage and select `Count Distinct Rows` for the Operation

[image]

**M-Code**

```
let
    Source = Excel.CurrentWorkbook(){[Name="Table1"]}[Content],
    #"Grouped Rows" = Table.Group(Source, {"Voyage"}, {{"Count", each Table.RowCount(Table.Distinct(_)), type number}})
in
    #"Grouped Rows"
```

**Source**

[image]

**Results**

[image]

Comment: That's excellent, cheers. I've got it bodged for now with a version based on David's suggestion below, but it looks like Power Query will be very useful and is probably a more effective solution in the long run. Thanks!

Comment: @AndrewPerry And it is easily updated if the source data changes. BTW, I had an unneeded operation.  It is not necessary to change the Day data type at all. That was for a different approach that I was considering, and I neglected to delete that step.  I have edited my answer to exclude that.

Answer (score 1):

Try this one:

`=IFERROR(INDEX($G$4:$G$1000, MATCH(0, INDEX(COUNTIF($H$4:H4, $G$4:$G$1000), 0, 0), 0)), "")`

I am assuming that the cells when you have the Ship+Date begins on G4. This formula on H4 and dragging down will report the values in your column that are uniques. (So if one of them is repeated, it will be shown one time only)

With this auxiliar column, you can use `COUNTIF` and you will get those days.

Hope it helps

Comment: Tried that now, but it just gives me a column full of 0. I'm not well up on index match, unfortunately, so I'm having some difficulty spotting where I'm going wrong.

Comment: I think you put me on the right course. I ended up using (here adjusted to fit the ranges in the full sheet) ``=IF(COUNTIF($AO$2:$AO2, [@TotID])=1, 1, 0)`` - and that did the trick. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Lets Suppose you are having Voyage in Cell A2 value B109 onwards and summary report starts from cell D3 contains the Voyage number B109 & E3 contains the count, then you can use =COUNTIF($A2:$A31,D2) in E3 and drag & drop for all unique voyage values
Refer the attached snapshot

[image]

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, because each find is submitted as a separate line item, that will output the number of individual finds rather than the number of days the ships have submitted reports. That's what's making it tricky... :-)